# How to add strings into an arraylist from a previous Activity

Tags: java, android

as the title says, I need to pass some strings from the current Activity (C) to a static ArrayList that was created in the first Activity (P). If I rotate the screen (C) before getting to the first Activity (P), all strings from previous Activity (C) are lost, but the main Activity ArrayList (P) still lives. If I get to the first Activity without any state change (a rotation), it all saves into the static ArrayList. What's wrong, why all arraylists (C) except the first one (P) are lost?

This is in my onCreate() method.

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b = getIntent().getExtras();    

    if (b != null) {

         myList = b.getStringArrayList("list");
         currentFile = b.getString("current");
         previousFile = b.getString("previousFile");         
    }
```

My code to create a new Activity:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();

        b.putString("current", currentFile);
        b.putString("previousFile", getPreviousFile())                                                     
        b.putStringArrayList("list", myList);       
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, str);
        i.putExtras(b);

        startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit please, so it is more clear which one is the Parent activity (P) and the child activity (C)? thanks

Comment: I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Basically, all ArrayLists from child activities are lost if the screen rotates, only AL from parent activity holds. I don't get it. For all activities I use the same layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you rotate the screen the activity is destroyed and recreated. It's the same as calling this.recreate();

To avoid this define this in the manifest, under activity:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

For instance:

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.app.example.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

You only really need the orientation and screensize, part, but it's good practice to use the others.

Comment: But how is possible that the first activity can keep arraylist after the rotate?

Comment: @slanecek, is the ArrayList created/populated in the onCreate() method of the first Activity? That could explain it.

In the event that the second activity is rotated, it's onCreate() method is called again, and it tries to find those values from the intent... which no longer exists since the activity wasn't created from an intent... it was recreated from itself and thus the bundled data is lost.

Either way, adding that code to the manifest will stop it being destroyed on the orientation changing.

Comment: @slanecek, no problem :) But you can avoid that by adding that code to the manifest. Creating a class would only be useful if you had multiple Activities using that data and you didn't want to bundle it up each time. IF you only do it once, you were right the first time... And adding that to the manifest is good practice anyway. Not really sure why Google would have the Activity recreated on rotation at all. Seems like an oversight on their behalf.

Answer (score -1):

Define in Manifest
             ->Example:

```
        android:name="pt.iscte.hff.activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
```

OR
Define this
MyProject/

    res/

        layout/

            main.xml

        layout-land/

            main.xml

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html